# Worklight logoutSuccess auth realm is undefined

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am not able to get Worklight logout working.

The logout button:

```
<input type="button" value="Logout2" onclick="WL.Client.logout('AuthRealm',{onSuccess: WL.Client.reloadApp})" />
```

When click to it I get:

```
onLogoutSuccess: realm: AuthRealm is undefined
```

But the realm is defined well and logout function of this realm is called after click. I investigated Worklight sources and found out that the problem is in:

```
onLogoutSuccess(transport=klass { request=klass, transport=XMLHttpRequest, readyState=4, more...})wlclient.js (line 1298)
```

So the error is thrown from:

```
if (typeof userInfo[realm] === "undefined") {
    WL.Logger.error('onLogoutSuccess: realm: ' + realm + ' is undefined');
    return;
}
```

Where should I set up userInfo? Or why is this error thrown? I didn't find any info in example sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce only when my device had not yet connected to the Worklight server in any way (has not yet logged into the realm, initOnStartup=false, no adapter calls, etc)

It appears that if the client has not yet communicated with the Worklight server, it knows nothing about the realm and so it throws an error when trying to log out of the realm. Try either adding a check to see if the user has logged into the realm or making sure that the user has connected to the Worklight server before they are able to log out.

Even if they haven't yet logged into the realm, the device will know about the realm if it has connected to the server at least once.

Comment: The problem was really, that I wasn't fully authorized as I didn't called the auth confirmation. Also I had multiple cookies which were badly affecting the application behaviour. This comes from my misunderstanding of the login proces in the Worklight. I tried to implement login page directly. When I changed the scenario and called some dummy secured resource, the authentication was succesfull and I didn't get into this problem again.